# How to create all possible combinations with two arrays

Tags: ruby

My problem now is to find the number in form a**b a,b < 100 that its, sum of digits is the largest, and to do so I decided to use arrays! I make two arrays a, and b like so:

```
a = []
b = []
(1..100).map {|n| a << n}
(1..100).map {|n| b << n}
```

and I also decided to make a sum_of_digits method:

```
class Integer
  def sum_of_digits
  self.to_s.split("").map {|p| p.to_i}.reduce(:+)
  end
end
```

So now I need to construct an array that contains all the combinations of a**b
How could I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: I would like to suggest a clarification (assuming I understand the question correctly): determine the maximum value of the sum of digits of the number i**j, among all pairs of integers i and j, 1 <= i <= 100, 1 <= j <= 100.  Note, in your `sum_of_digits` method, `self.` is not needed, as the receiver is `self`.

Answer (score 11):

You could use the [`Array#product`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-product) method:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]

a.product(b)
# => [[1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [2, 4], ...]

a.product(b).map { |x, y| x ** y }
# => [1, 1, 1, 16, 32, 64, 81, 243, 729]
```

Then, given your `Integer#sum_of_digits` definition:

```
a.product(b).map { |x, y| x ** y }.max_by(&:sum_of_digits)
# => 729
```

**Update**: to compute the maximum digital sum of the numbers (a ** b), where a, b are natural numbers less or equal to 100, I'd do like this:

```
Array(1..100)
  .repeated_permutation(2)
  .map { |a, b| (a ** b).sum_of_digits }
  .max
```

Comment: So what code would you use? the problem is exactly: A googol (10100) is a massive number: one followed by one-hundred zeros; 100100 is almost unimaginably large: one followed by two-hundred zeros. Despite their size, the sum of the digits in each number is only 1.

Considering natural numbers of the form, a**b, where a, b < 100, what is the maximum digital sum?

Comment: @user3127905 I've updated the answer, I hope I got it right now. Please edit your question to clarify as pointed out by Cary Swoveland.

Answer (score 2):

Skip the arrays and use the `repeated_permutation` helper on the range to get an enumerator:

```
(1..100).to_a.repeated_permutation(2)
```

Calling `to_a` on the enumerator will get you an array of all permutations.  However, you can operate on the enumerator directly to work more efficiently:

```
(1..100).to_a.repeated_permutation(2).reduce([0]) do |m,(a,b)| 
  r = (a**b).sum_of_digits
  r > m.last ? [[a,b],r] : m
end
=> [[99, 95], 972]
```

While you can call `map` and then find `max`. that will require actually holding all permutation results at once. Calling `reduce` on the enumerator will only require holding at any given time a single permutation and the result of the prior permutation.

Comment: Are you just saying, "use `permutation(2)`", as you make no reference to `a**b` or maximizing a sum of digits?

Comment: @CarySwoveland - you're right, I had misunderstood how the OP wanted to use these permutations.  Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: @PinnyM correctly pointed out that I should have used [Array#repeated_permutation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-repeated_permutation) rather than Array#permutation, because the latter does not include pairs `[i,i]`.  Rather than making the correction I've fix it slightly differently, in the interest of diversity, by replacing `a.permutation(2).to_a` with `a.permutation(2).to_a + a.zip(a)`.

```
  a = (1..100).to_a
  (a.permutation(2).to_a + a.zip(a)).map {|i,j| (i ** j).sum_of_digits}.max
    # => 972
```

And the winner is:

```
  (a.permutation(2).to_a + a.zip(a)).map \
    {|i,j| [i, j, (i ** j).sum_of_digits]}.max_by(&:last)
    # => [99, 95, 972] (99**95).sum_of_digits # => 972
```

If `i <= 3`, rather than `i <= 100`, the following steps are performed:

```
a = (1..3).to_a # => [1,2,3]
b = a.permutation(2) # => #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:permutation(2)>
c = b.to_a # => [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2]] 
d = a.zip(a) # => [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
e = c + d # => [[1,2], [1,3], [2,1], [2,3], [3,1], [3,2], [1,1], [2,2], [3,3]] 
f = e.map {|i,j| (i ** j).sum_of_digits} # => [1, 1, 2, 8, 3, 9, 1, 4, 9]
f.max # => 9
```

In Ruby 2.0 you can limit the use of the method `sum_of_digits` to your current context (e.g., class) by replacing `class Integer` with `refine Integer do`.  If you think you might want to use that method elsewhere, you could put it in a module and `include` the module where needed.

Comment: Actually, as others have mentioned, you'll need to use `repeated_permutation` (rather than `permutation`) since `i` and `j` may be the same number.

Answer (score 0):

```
combinations = []
a.each do |n1|
  b.each { |n2| combinations << n1**n2 }
end
```

edit:
you'll have all values double. Is that what you are searching for ?